# How to define Typescript function that takes a type as a strongly typed argument

Tags: typescript, inheritance, strong-typing, typescript3.0

I want to create a function that takes in a type (created with `export class` and imported normally) that extends a specific type. I have a `Page` class and many derived classes. In plain English, I'd like to have a function accept `Page`, `DerivedPage`, `AnotherDerivedPage` *classes* (not instances), obviously, trying to avoid `any` and keep strong typing.

How do I do it?

Comment: Something like: `function foo(ctor: new (...args) => Page) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the classes Page, DerivedPage, AnotherDerivedPage; you can use something as follows:

```
function foo (foo: Page | DerivedPage | AnotherDerivedPage)
```

If you want an argument which extends Page, probably below is the way to go:

```
function foo<T extends Page> (a: T) { ... }
```

**EDIT:**
Adding an example of such type to use with arrow functions

```
type foo<T extends Page> = (v: T) => void
const fn: foo<DeribedPage> = (v) => { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: `T extends Page` is exactly what I need. However, I was wondering if there's any way to apply it to an unnamed function? I've tried `function<T extends Page>(a: T){ ... }` but that didn't work.

Comment: Actually I've just tried the named example too, it doesn't work. It says `'>' expected` after I open `<`

Comment: Named example should work just fine. I just tried as well. Can you make sure there are no types? And I also edited my answer to show the type with arrow function. It might be useful for you depending in your actual case

Comment: Sorry, it was Vscode's bug. I've restarted Vscode and the syntax errors are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a constructor signature:

```
class Page {
    private p!: string;
}
class DerivedPage extends Page { }
class OtherPage extends Page { 
    constructor(param: number){
        super();
    }
}
class NotPage { private np!: string; }

function createPage(ctor: new (...a: any[])=> Page, ...a: any[]) {
    new ctor(...a);
}
```

Depending on need you can also create a more generic version that preserves parameter and class type:

```
//Preserves argument and class type
function genericCreatePage<T extends Page, A extends any[]>(ctor: new (...a: A)=> T, ...a:A){
    return new ctor(...a);
}

genericCreatePage(DerivedPage)
genericCreatePage(OtherPage, 0)
genericCreatePage(OtherPage, "0") //err
```